# How do I attach Jquery function to a HTML input

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have this code :

```
$(function (){

    $('#searchText2').keyup(function(event){
        if (event.which >= 38 && event.which <= 40)
            return;
        var val = $(this).val();
        jQTubeUtil.suggest(val, function(response){
            var html = '';
            for(s in response.suggestions){
                var sug = response.suggestions[s];
                html += '<li class="uli2"><a href="#">'+sug+'</a></li>';
            }
            if (response.suggestions.length)
                $('#autocomplete').html(html).show();
            else 
                $('#autocomplete').hide();
        });
    });

});
```

I would like to run this code when an input is onblur or onfocus with HTML: `<input name="q" type="text" onblur="**WHAT DO I PUT HER TO RUN CODE**">`

I did give the function a name but that did not work.

Comment: If you want the code to run on blur/focus, why not use http://api.jquery.com/blur/ and http://api.jquery.com/focus/? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I KNOW THIS, but I forgot....:-) (Thanks for the reminder...I feel stupid now...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't attach the event handler in the HTML.

You'll want to keep your JS (jQuery) code seperate from your HTML and to do this you can use the event handling mechanisms available to you in jQuery.

I see @Tatu just posted a code sample as I'm writing this so I wont add the same thing here.

The important part here is to know that you never need to use the HTML event attachment mechanism. It's outdated and rarely has a valid place these days.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind both events to do the same function:

```
$(function (){

    var myFunc = function(event){
        if (event.which >= 38 && event.which <= 40)
            return;
        var val = $(this).val();
        jQTubeUtil.suggest(val, function(response){
            var html = '';
            for(s in response.suggestions){
                var sug = response.suggestions[s];
                html += '<li class="uli2"><a href="#">'+sug+'</a></li>';
            }
            if (response.suggestions.length)
                $('#autocomplete').html(html).show();
            else 
                $('#autocomplete').hide();
        });
    }

    $('#searchText2').keyup(myFunc).blur(myFunc);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Add id to your input field like this :

```
<input name="q" id='tempId' type="text" onblur="**WHAT DO I PUT HER TO RUN CODE**">

$('#tempId').focus(function() {  
    // write your code for onfocus here
}).blur(function() {
    // write your code for blur here
});
```